# How to format String variable that is entered by the user from this (00000000) to this (0000-0000)

Tags: java

I trying to figure out how to change the format of the variable that is entered by the user, all I found online is how to format already known values but nothing else really. the only thing is for sure is that the user is instructed to enter eight numbers only.

```
`System.out.print("Please enter your ID: ");
clientID = input.next();
System.out.println("Welcome " + clientName + "(Client ID: " + clientID + "), to yout invesment portfolio.");`
```

I tried to use the "String.format" method but I couldn't figure out how to edit the variable at a certain index.

Comment: Try using String.substring() to extract pieces of the Input-String and concatenate it after with the wanted '-'

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
clientID = String.format("%s-%s", clientID.substring(0, 4), clientID.substring(4));
```

Or this

```
clientID = clientID.substring(0, 4) + "-" + clientID.substring(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use some regex for this kind of tasks. In this simple case, it is probably a little bit overkill, but in general with regex, you are a lot more flexible.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String pattern = "^(\\d{4})(\\d{4})$";
      
      String input = "12345678";
      String parsedInput = input.replaceAll(pattern, "$1-$2");

      System.out.println(parsedInput);
    }
}
```

First you define your pattern. In this case we say that we have two blocks `^(...)(...)$` where each contains exactly 4 `{4}` numbers `\d`.
With the `replaceAll` function, you then can rearrange these earlier defined blocks. They simply get numberd in order of appearance in the pattern. So `$1` references the first block, `$2` the second, and so on.
With that you can simply add the hypen in between the two blocks with `$1-$2`

Comment: or even just `input.replaceAll("(?<=^....)", "-")`